# XcodeBuild Framework in Jenkins Getting Error

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, frameworks, xcodebuild

Trying to build a framework with XcodeBuild in Jenkins. There are two files that should be produced:

```
foo.bundle
foo.framework
```

If I build in the command line, no problem:

```
xcodebuild -workspace foo.xcworkspace -sdk "iphoneos" -scheme "Framework"
```

But if I use that in Jenkins I get an error:

```
sh "xcodebuild -workspace \"${WORKSPACE}/app/${env.PROJECT_XC_WORKSPACE_FILE}\" -sdk \"iphoneos\" -scheme \"${schemeName}\""
```

The target compiles but eventually fails with:

> ❌  error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   can't locate file for: -lPods-FooSDKExternal
>
> ❌  error:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   file: -lPods-FooSDKExternal is not an object file (not allowed in a
>   library)

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you're working out of different working directories. Check your variables to see if 1.) They're outputting the same text as what your manual command is, and 2.) Verify you're using the same working directory as the manual command line entry.

Comment: I've added a cd command in front of the xcodebuild command (in the same sh invocation), cd'ing into the correct path but still getting the same errors. Checked the output of the sh command and it all looks the same as if called in the bash.

Comment: Figured it out: What made it work was to change `-sdk "iphoneos"` to `-sdk "iphonesimulator"`. :)